# Why is my layout being altered on different devices?

Tags: android, android-layout

So i have a simple fragment in an activity that renders correctly on some devices, but on other devices, components get moved around.

**This is what the layout should be like(samsung s4, s5):**

[image: This is what the layout should be like]

**But this is what happens on some devices(galaxy note):**

[image: This is what happens]

**layout.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">



<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/personName_su_il"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/ErrorText"
    app:hintAnimationEnabled="true"
    android:hint="Full Name"

    >
<EditText
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners_dark"

    android:id="@+id/personName_su"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/companyName_su_il"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/ErrorText"
    app:hintAnimationEnabled="true"
    android:hint="Company Name"
    android:layout_below="@+id/personName_su_il"

    >
<EditText
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners_dark"
    android:id="@+id/companyName_su"
    android:layout_below="@+id/personName_su_il"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/phoneNumber_su_il"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/ErrorText"
    app:hintAnimationEnabled="true"
    android:hint="Phone Number"
    android:layout_below="@+id/companyName_su_il"

    >
<EditText
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners_dark"
    android:id="@+id/phoneNumber_su"
    android:layout_below="@+id/companyName_su_il"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/physicalAddress_su_il"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/ErrorText"
    app:hintAnimationEnabled="true"
    android:hint="Physical Address"
    android:layout_below="@+id/phoneNumber_su_il"

    >
<EditText
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners_dark"
    android:id="@+id/physicalAddress_su"
    android:layout_below="@+id/phoneNumber_su_il"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/hourlyRate_su_il"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/ErrorText"
    app:hintAnimationEnabled="true"
    android:hint="Hourly Rate(Digits Only)(Optional)"
    android:layout_below="@+id/physicalAddress_su_il"

    >
<EditText
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners_dark"
    android:id="@+id/hourlyRate_su"
    android:layout_below="@+id/physicalAddress_su_il"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/emailAddress_su_il"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/ErrorText"
    app:hintAnimationEnabled="true"
    android:hint="Email Address"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hourlyRate_su_il"

    >
<EditText
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners_dark"
    android:id="@+id/emailAddress_su"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hourlyRate_su_il"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/password_su_il"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/ErrorText"
    app:hintAnimationEnabled="true"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:layout_below="@+id/emailAddress_su_il"

    >
<EditText
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners_dark"
    android:id="@+id/password_su"
    android:layout_below="@+id/emailAddress_su_il"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/activation_code_su_il"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/ErrorText"
    app:hintAnimationEnabled="true"
    android:hint="Activation Code"
    android:layout_below="@+id/password_su_il"

    >
    <EditText
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionGo"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corners_dark"
        android:id="@+id/activation_code_su"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password_su_il"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="profilePicture"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners_list"
    android:textColor="#f7f7f7"
    android:id="@+id/uploadProPicButton_su"
    android:layout_below="@+id/chosenCategories"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/proPicThumbnail"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_above="@+id/signUpButton_su"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/signUpButton_su" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/serviceCategory_su"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners_dark"
    android:layout_above="@+id/companyName_su_il"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/personName_su_il"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/townSpinner" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="register"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners_list"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#f7f7f7"
    android:id="@+id/signUpButton_su"
    android:layout_below="@+id/uploadProPicButton_su"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/viewPasswordButton"
    android:src="@mipmap/view_icon"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/password_su_il"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/password_su_il" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/countrySpinner"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners_dark"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/companyName_su_il"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/serviceCategory_su" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/townSpinner"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners_dark"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/phoneNumber_su_il"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/chosenCategories"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textColor="#484848"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners_dark"
    android:layout_below="@+id/activation_code_su_il"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/termsAndConditions"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use `Tools -> Android -> Layout Inspector` to understand what's happening.

Comment: I dont have the Layout Inspector option under Android. In using AS 2.1.2

Comment: Can you show your XML?

Comment: test ConstraintLayout https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Comment: @hermt2 , see edit

Comment: Its likely layout_alignParentEnd not working.  There were issues about that on some Samsung phones a few years ago.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan, would you recommend i use alignParentStart instead?

Comment: @GabeSechan, this happens on other layouts aswell that dont have alignParentStart